# Can you upgrade SQL Server 2008 SP2 Standard Edition to 2008 R2 Developer Edition?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a development server that was initially setup with SQL Server 2008 SP2 Standard Edition.  Is it possible to upgrade that edition to 2008 R2 Developer Edition so we can play with the extra features in Developer Edition?

Comment: We used the Standard Edition license was from our MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the version of the installed instance as far as I know, but you could install a second instance with the Dev edition, or uninstall the Standard edition, install Developer edition and attach the user databases.

Comment: I tested this and you are mostly correct.  You can only upgrade to a non-dev edition equal or higher than you already have. Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx